# Can a Fallen's Faith pool be greater than their permanent Faith?

Tags: world-of-darkness, demon-the-fallen

Going by the rules in the core rulebook for Demon: The Fallen (p. 159) a Fallen starts out with a number of points in its Faith pool equal to its permanent Faith. It then states that this pool can go down by spending its points and that it can be restored by ways of the Faith collected from Thralls. However, I do not see it stated that the upper limit of said pool is bound to the permanent Faith score in any way. Does the permanent Faith score impose such a limit? Or can the Faith pool be any arbitrary number as long as you collect enough of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you can't

Just like in other oWoD games that have permanent vs spendable pool resource (Willpower, Rage, Gnosis etc), you can't have temporary more Faith than your limit without spending Experience Points to increase this limit. Please compare to other traits that can move up and down above the initial value such as V:tM Humanity and Blood Points - on the character sheet you will see just a single row of fields contrary to the double row of (temporary and permanent) Willpower.

I know its a bit of circumstantial evidence, but I honestly believe that is the case.